# Detect when multiple static elements overlaps fixed element position on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to change the color of a fixed element (.logo) when scrolling on top of a dark image (.image). I came across this solution:

[Detect when static element overlaps fixed element position on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072680/detect-when-static-element-overlaps-fixed-element-position-on-scroll)

Which only works for a single image. But what if I want to change the color of the fixed element when scrolling passed all the images with the image class by using querySelectorAll?

I tried to solve this with a forEach but the fixed element only changes color on the last image. Can somebody explain this behaviour, in my mind this should work?

https://codepen.io/bosbode/pen/GaJNKr

HTML

```
<p class="logo">Logo</p>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.image {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0)
}
```

JavaScript

```
const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {

  const a = logo.getBoundingClientRect();

  images.forEach((item, index) => {

    const b = item.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (a.top <= (b.top + b.height) && (a.top + a.height) > b.top) {
      logo.style.color = 'white';
    } else {
      logo.style.color = 'black';
    }
  })

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var item = images[i]
    let b = item.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (a.top <= (b.top + b.height) && (a.top + a.height) > b.top) {
        logo.style.color = 'white';
        break;
    } else {
        logo.style.color = 'black';
    }
};
```

**Updated content:**
1. For this solution, I need using `break` [statement in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882842), so I am using `for` instead of `foreach`
2. We need `break` if logo is inside in every image.

**WHY?**:
If `logo` is inside `image1`, then its' color can be `white`, but next step, its' color can be `black`, because `logo`  is not inside `image2`.

**Below code is more readable for this solution:**

```
const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');

function isInsideInImages(images, logoPos) {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        let imagePos = images[i].getBoundingClientRect();

        if (logoPos.top <= (imagePos.top + imagePos.height) && (logoPos.top + logoPos.height) > imagePos.top) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    return false;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {

    const a = logo.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (isInsideInImages(images, a)) {
        logo.style.color = 'white';
    } else {
        logo.style.color = 'black';
    }

});
```